# Firebase: Get document snapshot after creating

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know that I can create a new query to read the doc by id in callback. But can I get the whole snapshot in the callback after creating document or at least TIMESTAMP?

```
firebase.firestore().collection("comments").add({
  body: data
})
.then(comment => {
  console.log(comment);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Please show the code you've tried

Comment: I have updated question

Comment: Your code doesn't show any date field. Please read [how to create an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it's the best way to ask for help for such code-related problems.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `CollectionRef.add(...)` return a reference to the newly created document. To be able to access the data of that new document you'll need to still load it. So:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("48486654").add({
  timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
})
.then(function(docRef) {
  docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.data().timestamp.toString());
  });
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

For a working example, see: https://jsbin.com/xorucej/edit?js,console

Comment: Yeah, I know that I can retrieve the doc after creating in separate query. What I'm asking is more util information in response callback, for example servertime of document creation. So we will not have to make another call just to get it.