# How to assign document id to a variable in firestore?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a firestore collection and am able to add data(documents) to it, and firestore automatically generates its document id.

**Adding data**

```
this.afs.collection('questions').add({ 'question': message, 'asker': this.currentStudent, 'upvotes': this.upvote, 'lesson': this.currentLesson });
```

I would like to get the document id of this newly added document and assign it to a variable, something like:

```
this.documentId = newlyGeneratedDocumentsId
```

I read somewhere that I can do this using the document.Set() method, if so, how may I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add()` methods returns a promise. When that promise resolves, it gives you the `DocumentReference` of the new document.

So you can get it with:

```
this.afs.collection('questions')
    .add({ 'question': message, 'asker': this.currentStudent, 'upvotes': this.upvote, 'lesson': this.currentLesson })
    .then(function(documentRef) {
        documentId = documentRef.id;
    });
```

Also see my answer here: [Firebase: Get document snapshot after creating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48486654/firebase-get-document-snapshot-after-creating/48488023#48488023)

Comment: This worked, but I am unable to assign it to a variable. I assigned it using `this.docId = documentRef.id`, and then when I console.logged `this.docId`, it returned undefined, however console logging documentRef.id returns the id.

Comment: There are two causes of that. 1) `this` inside the callback has a different meaning than outside of it. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484. 2) the code in the callback runs before the code after it, so you can only access the value *inside* the callback. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321.